# **nth package** generate full text: e.g. "1st" -> "first"

Tags: numbering, typography

I've been using the `nth` package ([for which there doesn't seem to be any documentation](http://tex.bootmath.com/where-is-the-documentation-for-the-nth-package.html)) to typeset my journal articles.

Now suddenly it turns out the journal wants full words for these descriptions. So "zeroth" instead of "0th" or "twenty-first" instead of "21st".

Is there an option for `nth` do do this for me, or do I have to go through the whole document and change everything?

Comment: The documentation exists: see the comments at the begining of the `sty` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can lend control to `fmtcount`, with no change in syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\newcommand{\nth}[1]{\ordinalstringnum{#1}}

\begin{document}

\nth{0}, \nth{1}, \nth{21}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: SUPER! it even has support for language specifics.

Comment: p.s. only one argument, so `\newcommand{\nth}{\ordinalstringnum}` is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

There may be, but I am not aware of a package that provides equivalent words for numbers.  Nonetheless, since one's use of `\nth` will generally be limited to a small finite number of instances, the following macro approach can be modified to provide the list needed for your work.  Ones not yet "translated" are shown in red as a reminder to update your macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nth,xcolor}
\let\svnth\nth
\def\umpteen{1000000}
\renewcommand\nth[1]{%
  \ifnum1=#1\relax first\else
  \ifnum2=#1\relax second\else
  \ifnum3=#1\relax third\else
  \ifx\umpteen#1\relax umpteenth\else
    \textcolor{red}{\svnth{#1}}% ADD MORE \if CLAUSES AS NEEDED
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
}
\begin{document}
The \nth{1}, \nth{2}, and \nth{3}, but not yet the \nth{4}.

For the \nth{\umpteen} time, clean your room!!
\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s.  For those with teenagers, **UPDATED** to provide support for the parentally invoked `\nth{\umpteen}`.

Comment: See my solution below witgh `moreenum`. Liked the teen comment though.

Answer (score 3):

I might suggest the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{moreenum,nth}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\let\onth\nth
\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\Nthwords{mycounter}}
\renewcommand{\nth}[1]{\setcounter{mycounter}{#1}\themycounter}
\begin{document}
\nth{278}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice indeed.